# Cleandestination in jasmine html reporter is not working

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing, jasmine2.0

I am using the following code to generate `HTML` report for e2e testing in protractor.

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
     baseDirectory: './e2e/e2e_coverage/',
     savePath: './e2e/e2e_coverage/',
     screenshotsFolder: 'images',
     takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
     cleanDestination: true,
     fixedScreenshotName: true,
     htmlReportDir: './e2e/e2e_coverage/htmlReports/',
     jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',
     docTitle: 'HTMLreport.html'
     }).getJasmine2Reporter());
```

Here, clean destination is not cleaning the previous run results. It is appending the previous run results which is generating duplicate results in `HTML` report.

I am using `protractor-beautiful-reporter version 1.2.7`.

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below in your `onPrepare()`

```
 // Add a screenshot reporter:
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            preserveDirectory: false,
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
            jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',
            baseDirectory: 'reports-tmp',

            pathBuilder: function pathBuilder(spec, descriptions, results, capabilities) {
                // Return '<30-12-2016>/<browser>/<specname>' as path for screenshots:
                // Example: '30-12-2016/firefox/list-should work'.
                var currentDate = new Date(),
                    day = currentDate.getDate(),
                    month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
                    year = currentDate.getFullYear();

                var validDescriptions = descriptions.map(function (description) {
                    return description.replace('/', '@');
                });

                return path.join(
                    day + "-" + month + "-" + year,
                    // capabilities.get('browserName'),
                    validDescriptions.join('-'));
            }
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());
```

There is no `cleanDestination`option in `protractor-beautiful-reporter version 1.2.7`.

Hope `preserveDirectory: false,`  would help you.

Comment: Thanks madhan ,adding preserveDirectory: false itself worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with below code . I tested in Version 5.4.2 of protractor with
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter

```
// protractor beautifulreporterconfig.js
//Add this import with path to exact node module to avoid the error 
var HtmlReporter = require('C:/Users/sam/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor-beautiful-reporter');

exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  //if your spec.js only have none angular scripts
  onPrepare: function () {
        // browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;// for non-angular set true. default value is false 
        //browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);   // for non-angular set false. default value is true  
      browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);

       }, 
 capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
chromeOptions: {
args: [ "--start-maximized" ]
         }
    },
     jasmineNodeOpts: {
            //Jasmine provides only one timeout option  timeout in milliseconds don't add ;
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
             },

             onPrepare: function() {
                // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/Reports/screenshots`:
                jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
                 baseDirectory: 'HtmlReports',
                screenshotsSubfolder: 'images', //sub folder for screenshots
                //Below settings are optional
                //Add title for the html report (optional)
                docTitle: 'my beautiful reporter',
                jsonsSubfolder: 'jsons',//You can store all JSONs in subfolder by using jsonsSubfolder option:
               //Exclude report for skipped test cases (optional)
                excludeSkippedSpecs: false,//default is false
                //Screenshots for skipped test cases (optional) Default is false.
                takeScreenShotsForSkippedSpecs: false,
                //Screenshots only for failed test cases (optional) default is false
                takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: false,
                //To Disable all screenshots default is false
                disableScreenshots: false,
                //You can gather browser logs using gatherBrowserLogs: option: default is true
                gatherBrowserLogs: true ,
                //You can preserve (or clear) the base directory using preserveDirectory: option:Default is true.
                // it it is true , report folder get cleared before the execution
                //If you want to show the total duration in the header or footer area...
                preserveDirectory: false,
                clientDefaults:{
                    showTotalDurationIn: "header",                  
                    totalDurationFormat: "hms"            
                }     


              }).getJasmine2Reporter());
},

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['src/com/sam/scriptjs/radiobutton.spec.js']


}
```